# slow xcopy startup script

Tags: batch-file, startup, xcopy

I have a .bat file using Xcopy to copy a folder.

I'm using this bat to run as startup script via Group Policy Editor

The .bat file contains:

```
xcopy "D:\temp\Temporary Firefox Files\*.*" "r:\TEMP\Temporary Firefox Files\"  /E /I /H /Y /C /Q
```

If I run it after logon it takes about 5 seconds to complete.

But when run at startup (before logon) it runs for about 2 minutes. (after logon I start task manager and see Xcopy process still running for 2 minutes).

As a hint, if I run the same .bat as shutdown script (also via GPO) it takes only 5 seconds to complete.

I'm testing this on Windows 7 Ultimate X64 and on Windows XP Professional X86. The result is the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: the time it takes to prepare the net client service, connect to the server and map the remote disk to R:

Comment: There is no server, and no remote disk is mapped. D:\ and R:\ are partitions on local disk.